# Обработка события закрытия Tab в JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Есть TabPane. В нем вложены 9 панелей Tab. Необходимо при закрытии каждого конкретного таба выполнять дополнительную функциональность. Как переопределить метод закрытия панели (нажатия на крестик).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У каждого `Tab` есть несколько событий связанных с закрытием:

- `onClosed` - происходит, когда `Tab` уже закрыт
- `onCloseRequest` - происходит, когда пользователь закрывает `Tab`

Скорей всего в вашем случае надо использовать `onClosed`

```
tab.setOnClosed((event) -> {
    // выполнить дополнительную функциональность.
});
```